# Delphi Component Assign Event on the fly

Tags: delphi, components, procedure

I have an ADOStoredProc on my form. It's not visual but in code.Normally it's pretty easy to handle an event if a component is visual.It's just a matter of double clicking the desired event. But how do I do it with code.I've declared a procedure:

```
 procedure SP_SearchAfterScroll(DataSet:TDataSet)
```

Now how do I assign SP_Search(this is the ADOStoredProc) AfterScroll event handler property to the procedure I wrote above. I'm sure you're going to answer it. So thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When SP_Search is the TAdoStoredProc and has an OnAfterScroll property, all you need to do is:

```
SP_Search.OnAfterScroll := SP_SearchAfterScroll;
```

I am assuming that you used the correct signature for SP_SearchAfterScroll. That is to say that the OnAfterScroll property has a type looks like:

```
TScrollEvent = procedure(DataSet: TDataSet) of object;
```

If the OnAfterScroll property has a type that differs from this, you will need to make sure that your SP_SearchAfterScroll procedure matches the parameters in that type.

**Edit**

In the comments Mikayil asked

> `SP_Search.AfterScroll :=
>   SP_SearchAfterScroll(SPSearch)'` the
>   compiler complains saying incompatible
>   types TNotifyEvent and procedure. But
>   when I write `SP_Search.AfterScroll :=
>   SP_SearchAfterScroll` it works. What's
>   the difference?

I hadn't gotten round to answering that and in the mean time **Mikey** explained it very well, so for (easier) future reference I am including his explanation up here:

> `SP_Search.AfterScroll :=` that code
>   assigns a function to handle the event
>   when it fires - you are not making a
>   call to SP_SearchAfterScroll at
>   'assign time' just assigning a value
>   to a variable, so you don't pass
>   parameter. Parameter is needed when
>   call is made - when event fires then
>   caller will assign parameter with the
>   right value. When you pass the
>   parameter,compiler assumes you are
>   calling the function, not assigning
>   it, so you get incompatible types
>   error. When you simply assign the
>   function without the parameter,
>   compiler understands you're assigning,
>   not calling the function.

Comment: Thank you Marjan, that did my job. But I wonder one thing. When I write SP_Search.AfterScroll:=SP_SearchAfterScroll(SPSearch) the compiler complains saying incompatible types TNotifyEvent and procedure. But when I write SP_Search.AfterScroll:=SP_SearchAfterScroll it works. What's the difference?

Comment: SP_Search passes the dataset when it calls the event internally

Comment: @Mikayil-'SP_Search.AfterScroll:='that code assigns a function to handle the event when it fires - you are not making a call to SP_SearchAfterScroll at 'assign time' just assigning a value to a variable, so you don't pass parameter. Parameter is needed when call is made - when event fires then caller will assign parameter with the right value. When you pass the parameter,compiler assumes you are calling the function, not assigning it, so you get incompatible types error. When you simply assign the function without the parameter, compiler understands you're assigning, not calling the function.

Comment: @Mikey: thanks for the explaning it to Mikayil. I hadden gotten round to it yet and as I couldn't have explained it any better, I have added yours to my answer so it may be easier to find.

Comment: @Marjan - thanks - it was hard to get the whole thing into only 600 chars!

Comment: @Mikey, perhaps being forced to get it into 600 chars is what helped make it so clear? :-)

Comment: @Mikayil- maybe a bit of additional explanation is appropriate (now I've got another 600 chars...): An 'event' is really just a 'function pointer' variable or 'callback' and all you're really doing when you set up an event handler, whether in the IDE or at runtime, is assigning the address of the function to be called, if and when the caller deems it appropriate - when an 'event fires' that's what's really happening.

Answer (score 0):

Declare as:

TDataSetNotifyEvent

- then it works